# Vim scripting: Preserve cursor position and screen view in function call

Tags: vim

I have some Vim functions that make changes to the document format. When I call this function, I currently use something like the following to save and restore my cursor position:

```
func! Foo()
  :norm mz
  ...
  :norm `z
endf
```

This properly saves the cursor position, but it sometimes changes the window position, so that the current line moves from being near the top of the screen to being near the bottom or vice versa. Is there a way to preserve both cursor position and the on-screen position of the line?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
let l:winview = winsaveview()
" do stuff
call winrestview(l:winview)
```

This should pretty much do exactly what you want it to do, possibly excepting the line count changing above the cursor (I suspect that deleted lines above the cursor would have the effect of moving the cursor down).

Comment: This works amazingly well, and is the clearest and most concise of the answers given so far.

Comment: Reading the documentation reveals all sorts of magic.  :)  I was very excited to find this myself as I had written an autocmd that did all sorts of formatting cleanups on file save but wanted the cursor back where it started.

Answer (score 9):

You can save a mark for the first on-screen line that is displayed in the window and restore that as well. An example that executes a `g?` command on the whole buffer and restores both positions:

```
:noremap <F11> mkHmlggg?G`lzt`k
```

Walking through the command:

- `mk`: set mark `k` for the current position
- `H`: go to the first on-screen line
- `ml`: set mark `l` for the this position
- `ggg?G`: execute the command
- ``l`: jump to mark`l`
- `zt`: set this line the first on-screen line
- ``k`: jump to mark`k`

Comment: Excellent answer! Works on VSCode VIM as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just :h getpos()

```
let save_cursor = getpos(".")
" MoveTheCursorAround
call setpos('.', save_cursor)
```

Comment: That will not work. As JS Bangs stated that he needs to restore the window position as well.

Answer (score 3):

you can use getline() to save the current buffer line and winline() to save the current window line.

So it would go something like this:

- save window line with winline()

  move the cursor to the top of the window with :normal! H

  save buffer line with getline()

  ...

  restore the buffer line with :exec 'normal! '.myline.'G'

  scroll to the top with :normal zt

  then restore the original window line with :exec 'normal! '.mywinline.'H'

There might be a few special cases you will have to take care of such as if the position is near the end or beginning of the file or if the file is smaller then the window size.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/jwhitley/vim-preserve) but I use a single function like this:

```
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
            let l:old_query = getreg('/')
            silent! execute 'keepjumps ' . a:command
         finally
            " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
            call setreg('/', l:old_query)
         endtry
    endfunction
endif
```

then I call it to clean trailing spaces

```
fun! CleanExtraSpaces()
    call Preserve(':%s/\s\+$//ge')
endfun
com! Cls :call CleanExtraSpaces()
au! BufwritePre * :call CleanExtraSpaces()
```

del blank lines

```
fun! DelBlankLines()
    call Preserve(':%s/^\n\{2,}/\r/ge')
endfun
command! -nargs=0 DelBlank :call DelBlankLines()
```

and change Header (Last Modified) information

```
fun! ChangeHeader()
    call Preserve(':1,5s/Last Change: \zs.*/\=strftime("%c")/e')
endfun
command! -nargs=0 CH :call ChangeHeader()
au BufWritePost * :call ChangeHeader()
```

Comment: For a robust solution, you should move your `Preserve()` function into an autoload plugin, execute the action in a `try` statement, and restore whatever you wish to restore in the associated `finally` clause.

Comment: This is a pattern I use quite often, but with another framework of mine to restore things. [Here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/blob/master/autoload/lh/dev/cpp/types.vim#L273) for instance, I restore the cursor position whatever I do in the mean time -- which makes me think that I could add a `register_cursorpos()` service to my [`lh#on#exit()` object](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/lh-vim-lib.txt#L524).