# Search "off the record" in Vim, or remove search pattern from search history?

Tags: search, macros, vim

I have in my .vrimrc cute little macros which add/remove c++ style comments from code:

```
" remove c++ style comment
nmap _ :s/^[ \t]*\/\///<CR>==:nohls<cr>
" comment line, c++ style
nmap - :s/^[ \t]*/\/\/ /<CR>==:nohls<cr>
```

These work by replacing the beginning of line pattern with another. In one case adding // and in another removing the slashes (if found).

The problem I bump into is that those macros use search-and-replace. As a result, unwanted search patterns are saved into vim's search history, cluttering it.

Consider the sequence:

1. Searched for 'hello'
2. Use the macro to comment a line
3. Search again (by typing 'n' or /,keyup,enter)
4. Result: the search does not look for 'hello', because the search pattern is set to whatever the macro was using, which is ^[ \t]*

How can this macro be modified to not inject unwanted patterns into the search history?

Comment: See `:help histdel()`.

Comment: See "Preserve" Function here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990794/2571881

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Save the current search register with `let old = @/`,
2. do your thing,
3. delete the last search from the history with `call histdel('/', -1)`,
4. restore the search register with `let @/ = old`.

Like this:

```
" remove c++ style comment
nnoremap <silent> _ :let old = @/<bar>s/^[ \t]*\/\///<CR>==:nohls<bar>call histdel('/', -1)<bar>let @/ = old<cr>
" comment line, c++ style
nnoremap <silent> - :let old = @/<bar>s/^[ \t]*/\/\/ /<CR>==:nohls<bar>call histdel('/', -1)<bar>let @/ = old<cr>
```

Or use Tim Pope's [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary).

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Also, I find 'commentary' very useful, I think I'll use it from now and on. The only issue I had with it was that it was clearing the multiple lines selection while toggling comments. That was easily solved by adding a 'gv' command which runs only in visual mode. For example:

    nmap - gcc
    vmap - gcgv

Answer (score 10):

Recent Vims have the `:keeppattern` modifier, which will prevent the pattern from adding to the history.

Comment: Does the `:keeppattern` modifier also save the search pattern flags? What about substitution flag? I think that would be nifty.

Comment: It doesn't save anything, but prevents, that the history will be poluted

Comment: Will using it prevent the search flags from being polluted? e.g. Search for something like `/foo/e` then if I run a like `:keeppattern /baz` will my next `n` be `/foo/e` or just `/foo`?

Comment: It will jump to /foo. There still seem to be some bugs.

Comment: Should be fixed by patches 7.4.150 and 7.4.155

Comment: @Christain Brandandt: That is fantastic! `:keeppattern` is now officially better than save/restoring the `@/` register due to the lack of vim variables or any kind of interface to get/set the search flags. Thank you for your hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there's a `search()` function, which doesn't touch the search history.

Comment: Note that calling commands like `:search()` from visual mode will exit that mode, freeing the selection. Recalling it within the same macro would be something like `v\`>` or `v\`<` depending on whether the search was forward or backward.